# (org-babel-load-file (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/config.org")) behaves strangely on Windows 7

Tags: init-file, org-babel, microsoft-windows

In my initialization file the line

```
(when (file-readable-p "~/.emacs.d/config.org")
 (org-babel-load-file (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/config.org")))
```

give me the error:

*Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘c:/Users/TR/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/init.el’:

File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, c:/Users/TR/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/config.el*

as i understand instead of the file name i gave to it(config.org) it is looking another file with .el extension(config.el).

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: org-babel-load-file first apply org-babel-tangle, which is probably buggy and not generate a config.el file. Try to load your config.org file and tangle interactively (C-c C-v C-t = M-x org-babel-tangle). You should get the messages "Wrote /your/path/to/config.el" and  "Tangled N code blocks from config.org".
If not you can get some clues for the errors in your config.org file.

Comment: I get this one "Tangled 0 code blocks from config.org"

Comment: The code blocks are probably syntactically incorrect.
Since I'm not a diviner, I don't know why.  Only you can find out unless you post them.

Comment: when i try C-c ' in config.org it gives me the error: "No special environment to edit here." may be it is related to it